# Reading dates from a NetCDF file using Fortran

Tags: date, datetime, calendar, fortran, netcdf

I have to use Fortran for some calculations using data from NetCDF files. And, depending on user selections, I need to select only one or some months from each year.

The dates in the NetCDF file are coded sometimes as "months since XXXX-XX-XX", other times as "days since XXXX-XX-XX", others as "hours since XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX", etc.

In addition, these have to be interpreted as belonging to a certain type of calendar, which can be Gregorian, Julian, proleptic Gregorian, 360-day, etc.

After many searches I have a plan to attack this problem, but want to ask the experts before.

My plan is as follows:

1. Use the [UDUNITS package](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/udunits/) to convert the date information contained in the NetCDF file, to a Julian/Gregorian date. For this, I have to:

   - Bind the C code of UDUNITS to Fortran.
2. Convert the date obtained, to the desired calendar. For this, I think that I have to use a calendar package. Which would be a good choice?.

Do you agree with this?

Comment: your link is broken. the alternative would be to do it yourself, which simplifies a good bit if you dont care to accurately deal with dates prior to 1580..

Comment: No, I don't agree. Really, what is the real question? You can take a look at https://github.com/milancurcic/datetime-fortran made by one of SO Fortran experts.

Comment: It seems they updated the version of udunits. I have updated the link, so it works now.

Comment: I seems the libraries you propose are intended to do operations with times and dates, but not to convert them from one calendar to another. This is needed because the dates in netcdf files are stored in many different calendar types. You can encounter for example, the ones that I listed in my question.

Comment: If you find a netcdf file with a 360-days calendar and with dates defined as "days since 2000-12-29", there is an integer assigned to each time step. The first ones can be: 0, 1, 2, 3, .. and has to be interpreted as 2000-12-29, 2000-12-30, 2001-01-01, 2001-01-02, ..., but in a gregorian calendar, it must be interpreted as 2000-12-29, 2000-12-30, 2000-12-31, 2001-01-01, ...

Comment: OK, so what is the question?

Comment: The question is to interpret the integers assigned to each time step as dates like 2000-12-20, according to the type of calendar specified in the netcdf file. Also, it would be useful to make operations between dates according to its own type of calendar. The libraries you told about makes it with the gregorian calendar, but not with others.

Comment: That is not a real question for Stack Overflow, that is a full project assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a good solution: the [cdi libraries](https://code.zmaw.de/projects/cdi), developed by the Max-Plank Institute and distributed under the GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 2.

It defines the following types of calendars: CALENDAR STANDARD, CALENDAR PROLEPTIC, CALENDAR 360DAYS, CALENDAR 365DAYS and CALENDAR 366DAYS.

This seems to be a very proven code, since it is used by cdo, a widely used tool that manages netcdf files.

Comment: Just a question: if I develop a useful library to manage netcdf files based on these libraries, where could I post the code to people that can fint it useful?.

Comment: Wherever, there are many sites http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_software_hosting_facilities